# Difficulty understanding this type signature

Tags: scala

merge sort type signature :

```
def msort[T](less: (T, T) => Boolean)(xs: List[T]): List[T] = {
```

The function is called using :

```
msort[Int]((a, b) => a < b) _
```

Does the type msort[Int] type the parameters a & b to Int ?

To better understand this type signature I've tried to extract the less function :

```
  def lessFunc[Int]((a , b) : (Int , Int)) : Boolean = {

    true

  }
```

But this is not correct ?

Entire code :

```
def msort[T](less: (T, T) => Boolean)(xs: List[T]): List[T] = {
    def merge(xs: List[T], ys: List[T], acc: List[T]): List[T] =
      (xs, ys) match {
        case (Nil, _) => ys.reverse ::: acc
        case (_, Nil) => xs.reverse ::: acc
        case (x :: xs1, y :: ys1) =>
          if (less(x, y)) merge(xs1, ys, x :: acc)
          else merge(xs, ys1, y :: acc)
      }
    val n = xs.length / 2
    if (n == 0) xs
    else {
      val (ys, zs) = xs splitAt n
      merge(msort(less)(ys), msort(less)(zs), Nil).reverse
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a function which takes two lists of parameters. The first list contains a `less` function, which as you've guessed correctly when invoked with `[Int]` is typing the parameters to `Int`.

You have just expanded it wrong. What you should have done is

```
def less(a: Int, b: Int) = true
```

or to match your anonymous function

```
def less(a: Int, b: Int) = a < b
```

Now when you call your `msort` like `msort[Int](less) _` (see [currying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309501/scala-currying-vs-partially-applied-functions))  you'll get a new function which is able to sort `Lits[Int]`.

```
val listSorter = msort[Int](less) _
listSorter(List(1, 2, 3))
```

Answer (score 1):

`def msort[T](less: (T, T) => Boolean)(xs: List[T]): List[T]`

is a function with two parameter lists that returns List of type `T`. First parentheses let you pass a function that will be used for sorting the list.

`(T,T) => Boolean`  - means that the function will take two parameters and yield boolean.

The second parentheses take a List of type `T` . This `T` after name of the function is like generics in Java. You use it to pass a type. It can be called like:

`def msort[String]((a,b) => a.length < b.length)(some list)` if you want to sort `List` of `String`'s by their length. Or  you can call it like in the example to sort `List` of `Int`s

`def msort[Int]((a,b) => a < b)(some list)`

Because function is defined with two sets of parameters we can take advantage of it by applying only part of them and build specialised functions based on that one. Like for example:

`val stringSort = msort[String]((a,b) => a.length < b.length) _`

`val ascendingIntSort = msort[Int]((a,b) => a < b) _`

These are curried functions because `stringSort`'s signature is `List[Strint] => List[String]`. Now you can reuse these methods by passing only instances of `List`s to them:

`stringSort(List("cat", "elephant", "butterfly"))`

`ascendingIntSort(List(4,1,3,2))`

Comment: Re the 1st method signature: It is a method with two argument lists, not a curried function. Why is this confusion so widespread?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. My mistake. Already fixed. Confusion probably comes from the fact that in terms of functionality we don't get much of a difference.