# What are the performance characteristics between curried, partially applied, and 'normal' functions in Scala?

Tags: performance, scala, benchmarking, currying, partial-application

I took a look here: [Scala currying vs partially applied functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309501/scala-currying-vs-partially-applied-functions), but the answers there answer more about the functional and semantic differences between currying, partial application, and normal functions in Scala.

I'm interested in learning whether there are any performance considerations between these different techniques that can be used on functions,  namely...

If we use the performance of a normal function as a base:

```
def add3(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int) = a + b + c
add3(1, 2, 3)
```

And then compare to:

```
// First
(add3 _).curried(1)(2)(3)

// Second
val add2 = add3(1, _: Int, _: Int)
val add1 = add2(2, _: Int)
add1(3)

// Third
def add3(a: Int)(b: Int)(c: Int) = a + b + c
add3(1)(2)(3)
```

What are the things I might want to be mindful of if I've identified some poorly performing code (either in terms of speed or memory usage) and I see a lot of currying or partial application happening in said code segment?

In Haskell I would, for instance, be looking at how many thunks are being generated and hanging around.  I'd presume Scala uses a similar sort of method for passing around partially applied and curried functions, and the details of how Scala handles these things would be valuable to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used my [scala-to-java tool](https://github.com/Aivean/scala-to-java) to convert your snippets to java, and here are results:

1. Simple function call is transpiled to similar function call:

   ```
   def add3(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int) = a + b + c
   add3(1, 2, 3)
   ```

   Result:

   ```
   public final class _$$anon$1 {
       private int add3(final int a, final int b, final int c) {
           return a + b + c;
       }

       {
           this.add3(1, 2, 3);
       }
   }
   ```
2. "First" snippet: `(add3 _).curried(1)(2)(3)` is transpiled essentially into into this:

   ```
   ((Function3<Integer, Object, Object, Object>)new _$$anon$1$$anonfun._$$anon$1$$anonfun$1(this)).curried().apply(BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger(1)).apply(BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger(2)).apply$mcII$sp(3);
   ```

   I omitted boilerplate. What happens here is wrapper function class is created around `add3`, then method `curried` of that class is called, then `apply` is called three times on the result of the previous application. You can check the sources of `curried` [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/99a82be91cbb85239f70508f6695c6b21fd3558c/src/library/scala/Function3.scala). What it does, it just returns several high-order functions (function that return function).

   So, comparing to "case 0", several extra function wrappers are created for single curried call.
3. "Second":

   ```
   // Second
   val add2 = add3(1, _: Int, _: Int)
   val add1 = add2(2, _: Int)
   add1(3)
   ```

   I will not provide the whole page of transpiled output. Check it [here](https://gist.github.com/Aivean/9d10df37e6c4c2554f37385bf5391ae5) if you want. Essentially what happens is for `add2` and `add1` functional wrapper class is generated with single method that takes corresponding number of arguments. So, when you call `add1(3)`, it calls `add2` which calls `add3`. Generated wrappers are effectively singletons, so the overhead is limited to several function calls.
4. Third:

   ```
   def add3(a: Int)(b: Int)(c: Int) = a + b + c
   add3(1)(2)(3)
   ```

   Is transpiled to simple function call again:

   ```
   public final class _$$anon$1 {
       private int add3(final int a, final int b, final int c) {
           return a + b + c;
       }

       {
           this.add3(1, 2, 3);
       }
   }
   ```

   but if you try to use it in curried way, for example, like this `val p = add3(1) _`, a functional wrapper class will be additionally generated.

Comment: What I gather from this is that the overhead of currying and partially applying functions in Scala is mostly negligible, because it creates singleton classes for returning each result function, which amount practically to a simple function call for the most part.