# Underscore after function?

Tags: scala

Given

```
scala> def method(x: Int) = x
method: (x: Int)Int

scala> val func = (x: Int) => x
func: Int => Int = <function1>
```

Consider the following code:

```
scala> method _
res0: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> func(_)
res1: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> func _
res2: () => Int => Int = <function0>
```

I can understand that `res0` is eta expansion and `res1` is equivalent to lambda function `(x) => func(x)`. But I cannot figure out the output of `res2`. Could anyone please explain that for me?

Comment: @kokorins yep, I've edited. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is actually a bit tricky. First, let's see what happens outside REPL:

It *doesn't* work when `func` is a local variable:

```
object Main extends App {
  def foo() = {
    val f = (_: Int) + 1
    f _
  }

  println(foo())
}

[error] /tmp/rendereraEZGWf9f1Q/src/main/scala/test.scala:8: _ must follow method; cannot follow Int => Int
[error]     f _
[error]     ^
```

But if you put it outside `def foo`, it compiles:

```
object Main extends App {
  val f = (_: Int) + 1
  val f1 = f _

  println(f1)
}
```

because `f` is both a *field* of `Main` and a *method* without arguments which returns the value of this field.

The final piece is that REPL wraps each line into an object (because Scala doesn't allow code to appear outside a trait/class/object), so

```
scala> val func = (x: Int) => x
func: Int => Int = <function1>
```

is really something like

```
object Line1 {
  val func = (x: Int) => x
}
import Line1._
// print result
```

So `func` on the next line refers to `Line1.func` which is a method and so can be eta-expanded.

Comment: So it turns out that it's still eta expansion working. Really great explanation, thank you!

Comment: Excellent analysis. Thanks.

Comment: Just curious, in regarding explanation "because f is both a field of Main and a method without arguments which returns the value of this field."..... .. question is, do you call f as  'method' in the same way as discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2530007/4582240 ? to me it is not a method, instead is Value Declarations and Definitions (Function Type and Anonymous Functions).

Comment: @MinnieShi Maybe I could have said "can be considered a method". See https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#method-values: "The expression `e _` is well-formed if `e` is of method type or if `e` is a call-by-name parameter." And `f` is certainly not a by-name parameter.

Comment: @MinnieShi Also, yes it is a value declaration of function type; but that's also true in the local variable case, and the major point of my answer was to explain the difference between these cases.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question about `res2` - the appended underscore `_` syntax is used to partially apply a function.

So.

```
scala> func _
```

Means you have partially applied your `<function1>`. 
This results in a new curried form, the first function of which takes zero arguments (hence `<function0>`)

```
() =>
```

Which returns your original `<function1>` which takes 1 argument.

```
Int => Int = <function1>
```

The complete result being the chain of functions.

```
res2: () => Int => Int = <function0>
```

The rule that might be useful for you to remember is that functions associate to the right so the following are equivalent.

```
() => Int => Int    
() => (Int => Int)
```

[This other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309501/scala-currying-vs-partially-applied-functions?answertab=active#tab-top) might be useful reading for you.

Answer (score 3):

You've used the eta Expansion to turn `res2` into a function that takes 0 parameters and returns a function that takes a single parameter.

```
res2: () => Int => Int = <function0>
```

So you can now do this:

```
val zero = func _
val f: Int => Int = zero()
```

Comment: So you mean it's eta expansion again? All I know about eta expansion is that it extracts the method value(i.e. a function) from a method. But I cannot see in my example why this applies.

Comment: You can add the underscore to any function. If you define a function `val x = (a: Int) => a` this: `val y = x _` works without a hitch and returns a `Function0`.

Comment: Yep, I knew it.What I am asking is why this happens?

Comment: Hi @Luka, I did not understand what you meant at the beginning. After reading Alexey Romanov's answer, I see what's happening. You are right that it's just eta expansion. But I did not realize that each line in REPL will be wrapped into a object(I am new to Scala :P). Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
val func1 = func _
```

This returns a function0 which takes no arguments and returns the `func` function.

You can use this like:

```
func1()(2) // outputs 2
```

You can continue doing this kind of expansion ad infinitum:

```
val func2 = func1 _

func2()()(2) // outputs 2
```

Comment: I saw what happens, but I cannot explain why. Is it a special syntax? or just a less obvious use of some known syntax?

Comment: I see what you are trying to understand. Seems like eta expansion is happening on functions too. But language specification says its only applicable on methods or call by name parameters of type: => T

Comment: Yep, so I am kind of curious about what is happening ; )

Comment: Alexey Romanov gives a great explanation. It turns out that eta expansion is what's happening. Hope it helps!